# Extracting Only Year Value in Crystal Report DateTime Field

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, formula

I am working with Crystal Report, right now I am in a situtation where I have to extract only Year value from a datetiem field,
for example,
if the value is : **01/03/2014 10:20:01AM**

I only need to extract **2014**

I did what is that , I changed the DataFormat of the field is dd/mm/yyyyy

Now i hav eapplied formula on it.

```
Formula = Right(CStr ({report;1.FirstYearDate}),4)
```

It shows **01AM**

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I have done with this way,
my string was **"01/02/2012 10:45:22Am"**

after using this formula:

```
Formula = ToText({report_;1.FirstYearDate}, "yyyy")
```

I have got this value :**2012**

Comment: Error - Too Many Arguments supplied, "yyyy" is unexpected in Crystal Designer 2013

Answer (score 4):

try this way

```
Year(Cdatetime(<<your date time value here>>));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Year (DateValue ({Orders.Order Date}))
```

Here for example date field is `Order date` from  Orders table.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. My reporting scenario had -
`{Orders.POST_DATE}` in `minimum(YearToDate)` to `maximum(LastFullMonth)`.

That was working fine until it was run in a new year. Then Crystal read the dates as the last day of last month and the first day of the new year.

After seeing the solution here. I modified my code this way, which works:

`{Orders.POST_DATE}` in `DateSerial(Year (minimum(LastFullMonth)), 1,1)` to `maximum(LastFullMonth)` which now forces the 1/1/yyyy to be the same year as the year in LastFullMonth.